# Drop a foreign key constraint between columns of two tables without knowing the foreign key name in Informix?

Tags: mysql, informix

I'm using an Informix database.  I have added some foreign keys to a table without giving them a name e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE myreport
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES report(id),
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user(id);
```

Now I want to delete the foreign key between `uid` and `id` of `user` table.

I can get the name of the constraints on the table using the following:

```
SELECT constrname
  FROM sysconstraints
 WHERE tabid = (SELECT tabid FROM systables WHERE tabname = 'myreport');
```

which gives following output:

```
constrname  u169_201    
constrname  n169_202
constrname  n169_203
constrname  n169_204
constrname  n169_205
constrname  n169_206
constrname  n169_207
constrname  r169_276
constrname  r169_277
```

I don't know which constraint belongs to the foreign key between `uid` and `id` of `user` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following it worked:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INFORMIX.REMOVE_FK()
    DEFINE tmpvr varchar(250);
    FOREACH cur1 FOR select  b.constrname into tmpvr
            from systables a, sysconstraints b, sysindexes c, syscolumns d
            WHERE a.tabname = 'myreport' AND (d.colname='uid' or d.colname='rid')
            AND b.tabid = a.tabid AND c.idxname = b.idxname AND d.tabid = a.tabid AND (
                d.colno = c.part1 or d.colno = c.part2 or d.colno = c.part3 or d.colno = c.part4 or
                d.colno = c.part5 or d.colno = c.part6 or d.colno = c.part7 or d.colno = c.part8 or
                d.colno = c.part9 or d.colno = c.part10 or d.colno = c.part11 or d.colno = c.part12 or
                d.colno = c.part13 or d.colno = c.part14 or d.colno = c.part15 or d.colno = c.part16
            )
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE myreport DROP CONSTRAINT (' || tmpvr || ')';
    END FOREACH
END PROCEDURE;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE INFORMIX.REMOVE_FK();
DROP PROCEDURE INFORMIX.REMOVE_FK();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `sysreferences` catalog table. Something like this should give you the information you need:

```
SELECT
    c_a.constrname AS Constraint_name
    , t_a.tabname AS ForeignKey_table
    , i_a.idxname AS ForeignKey_index
    , t_b.tabname AS PrimaryKey_table
    , i_b.idxname AS PrimaryKey_index 
FROM
    sysreferences AS r
    INNER JOIN sysconstraints AS c_a
    ON 
        r.constrid = c_a.constrid
    INNER JOIN systables AS t_a
    ON 
        c_a.tabid = t_a.tabid
    INNER JOIN systables AS t_b
    ON 
        r.ptabid = t_b.tabid
    INNER JOIN sysindexes AS i_a
    ON
        c_a.idxname = i_a.idxname
    INNER JOIN sysconstraints AS c_b
    ON
        r.primary = c_b.constrid
    INNER JOIN sysindexes AS i_b
    ON
        c_b.idxname = i_b.idxname 
WHERE
    t_a.tabname = 'YOUR_TABLE_HERE';
```

Comment: But how to drop constrains based on output bcz DROP CONSTRAINS doesnot expects a dynamic values..

Comment: You either use an external tool to query for the constraint names and then build and execute the `DROP` statement or you create a stored procedure in the Informix database (search for Dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`).

Comment: Can u suggest a stored procedure?

Comment: For the information displayed, you could replace `i_a.idxname` in the select-list with `c_a.idxname` and `i_b.idxname` with `c_b.idxname`, and then drop both the references `sysindexes`.  If you wanted to list one or more of the indexed column numbers, you'd need to include `sysindexes`, of course. For the first indexed column from each table, you'd select from `syscolumns` twice to get the corresponding column names. Extending beyond the first column is fraught, especially if you want to deal with any index with 2-16 columns referenced. Fortunately, you'll seldom need that many index columns.